# Significant number determination

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

Expressing magnutitudes with units and significant numbers which reflect the sensitivity of our measurement devices seems to be important in physics. When adding/ subtracting two numbers we report the result considering the decimal place of the most ambigious number ( ambigious here is used in the sense of 15 being more ambigious than 15.0 and 15.0 being more ambigious than 15.00) . So if we add 12 with 15.09 our result should be reported as 27. When multiplying or dividing, what we do is to consider not the place of the decimal but the  number with the least amount og significant numbers. For example when we divide 37.5 to 4.425 we should report 8.47 as our answer since 37.5 has 3 significant number and 4.425 has 4. I was wondering how this case works for square root operation. Do the rules of multiplication and division hold for square root?